# Exclude spring.factories dependencies for Spring Boot test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

There is one parent project A and the project which is using A's dependencies let's called it as B.
Everything is working fine except testcases. I am using SpringBootTest which is fetching all the dependencies from spring.factories of project A. I want to disable these dependencies for project B for testcases but need it to run project B.
The spring.factories file present in META-INF of project A contains -

```
1. org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration
2. org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration
3. org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor.
```

Each with packages of project A.

I tried using Import annotation and passed my own configuration. ConponentScan annotation with project B base package. But nothing really helped.

Answer (score 0):

If those factories are a compile-time dependency for `A` then it won't be possible to exclude them only at test time for `B`.  However, if they are not needed at compile time, but only at runtime, then you may be able to use the `runtime` scope for those dependencies to solve the problem.

With that said, I personally avoid this type of grey-box testing.  Here's a link to a blog that may help: https://github.com/savoirtech/black-box-system-test.